# How to implement random generated number into a variable in setter or getter?

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to OOP java. What is the best way to implement this. I want to generate  seven random number into accountNumber? Do i put the equation to the setter or constructor?

```
private int accountNumber;
private float  balance;
private String customerName;
private String email;
private String phoneNumber;


public Account(int accountNumber, float balance, String customerName, String email, String phoneNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.customerName = customerName;
    this.email = email;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: `this.accountNumber=new Random().nextInt(50)` ? or `public int getAccountNumber(){ return new Random().nextInt(50)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the 'equation' in constructor, so each object created for class Account will have a un-modifiable value (making it in unique).

If you put the 'equation' in getter or setter, the value varies each time these methods are called.

Finally, it depends upon your requirement. If you are going to re-use the Account class object, its best to put the formula in setter. If you are going to create multiple objects for class Account then go with constructor (recommended practice).

For generating random numbers, you can use `Math.random` or `java.util.Random`

Comment: I'd recommend OP avoid doing any calculations in the constructor. They could instead create a factory method, generate the number as part of that function, and pass it into the constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the randomization into the getter then it will randomize the account number every time the getter is called. Unless you want a random account number each time, you should put it in the constructor so that it is only randomized on initialization.

In the constructor you can do:

```
this.accountNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 9000000) + 1000000;
```

which will set accountNumber to be a random number from 1,000,000 to 9,999,999.

Answer (score 0):

As oop you should be use a separate method to generate  Account number .....
inside method i use @Mihir code

```
public int generateAccountNumber() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 9000000) + 1000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `java.util.Random`. try out below code,

```
private static Random random = null; //static Random instance
int min = 999999; //minimum number
int max = 9999999; //maximum number

public Account(float balance, String customerName, String email, String phoneNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = getRandom().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; //generating a new random number with length of seven
    this.balance = balance;
    this.customerName = customerName;
    this.email = email;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
public static Random getRandom() {
    if (Objects.isNull(random)) {
        random = new Random(); //Creates new Random instance only if random is null
    }
    return random; //return a Random instance
}
```

Comment: you can use Integer.MAX_VALUE instead of specifying it as 9999999

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE seems to be 2147483647 in java. I think this won't replace 9999999.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel for random number generation , you can probably use Apache Commons RandomStringUtils class.

```
RandomStringUtils.random(9) // Creates a random string whose length is the number of characters specified(9 for example).
```

Reference -https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html

Comment: I don't believe this would necessarily create a numeric String that could be parsed into an int for the accountNumber.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.I will take note on this also :).

Comment: You can always convert a String to Int however having account number as int can be considered as poor design , as later it might lead to overflow issues.

Answer (score 0):

Java Provides 3 ways to generate Random Numbers:

1. Random class from the java.util package
2. Math.Random method
3. ThreadLocalRandom class

By using this we can generate random numbers based on the applicaiton.

Comment: Thank very much for the information.I really appreciate it.